# Connecting a "master node" with specific subnodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We create multiple graphs based on versions of a program (A,B in my example)

```
(:ProgNode {compileUnit:RL105A, nodeKey:100, captureDate:1/1/1} )
(:ProgNode {compileUnit:RL105B}, nodeKey:200,captureDate:2/2/2} )
```

these fan out into full blown graphs with thousands of nodes. We also have a single node `(:ProgUnit{compileUnit:RL105})` 
that is a "master" node for that program. We want to link the first node of each individual subgraph (the lowest nodeKey ) to the master.  My current query looks like this

```
MATCH (p:ProgNode) where p.compileUnit = 'RL105A' WITH min(p.nodeKey) as low_node 
Match (j:ProgUnit) where j.compileUnit = 'RL105' 
Create (j)-[r:RELEASE]->(p)
```

A and B will eventually be dates but for now, letters

This works (sort of), but instead of linking the master to the subgraph, it seems to create a new node which isn't anything.

I know I will have to run this 2 times to build both links (A,B) and thats not an issue.

Thoughts ? What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Because you use `create` and not a `merge`, every time you run this query, it will create a new edge. But it should not create a new node. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Ahh I missed that, thank you. I dont need more edges ! But yes, very sure. Its almost like the output of P isnt a node address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WITH` clause did not include `p` as a term, so `p` became an unbound variable again.

The following query should create a `RELEASE` relationship to the `ProgNode` whose `compileUnit` starts with "RL105" and whose `nodeKey` has the lowest value:

```
MATCH (p:ProgNode) WHERE p.compileUnit STARTS WITH 'RL105'
WITH p ORDER BY p.nodeKey LIMIT 1
MATCH (j:ProgUnit) WHERE j.compileUnit = 'RL105'  
CREATE (j)-[:RELEASE]->(p)
```

Use `MERGE` instead of `CREATE` if you need to avoid creating duplicate relationships.

Comment: Dang - That worked and yes, I see. Sorry - That one seems pretty basic. The scope of the with wasnt clear to me. Thank you